# Função NS_LOG - NS3(Network Simulator): O que significa o operador "<<" na pratica?

Tags: c++, operadores, binary, redes

Estou trabalhando com o programa ns3, e tentando entender o código que tenho em mãos, me deparei com essa linha, e gostaria de saber o que essa sequencia de "<<" significa.(Não me refiro as variaveis, mas sim ao comando "<<")

Li sobre o assunto e encontrei isso: desloca para a esquerda e adiciona zeros na extremidade direita, mas isso é verdade entre 2 valores. Não sei o que significa de modo encadeado como mostrado na função abaixo.

```
NS_LOG_FUNCTION (this << tcb << packetsAcked << rtt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso é um operador de deslocamento de bits a esquerda: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/336xbhcz.aspx